# DateTime To Excel Region Issue

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am strongly typing my DataTable DateTime columns and then transforming the DataTable into an Object[,] and pasting into Excel. My problem is that in some cases the date shows in US format and in others UK format. What is the standard practise for doing this operation and making sure that the correct date is pasted down but also maintaining the type of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C# Excel Interop, you can set the Format of a cell or a range of cells with the `NumberFormat` property.

This is just a string, and is the same thing that you would type into Excel if you right clicked on a cell, or a range of cells and selected the `Custom` category, and then typed in a format.

You could ensure that a Date in a cell always has the same format by simply doing the below:

```
range.Value = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
range.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy";
```

Comment: I would never set dates from a string value and use DateTime.Now.ToOADate(); instead.

Comment: Very true, I was answering the question in regards to the cell format, I have updated the answer

Comment: what is the advantage of posting as an OLE Automation Date vs just DateTime, is there any benefit in this?

Comment: Excel stores Dates as OLE Automation Dates by default. In Excel if you type in a date, then right click on the cell and change the format to `Text`, this will change to a series of numbers, which is the date in OLE Automation Date format. By providing the Date in text format, you are giving Excel extra work to do.

Comment: maybe there isnt much of a difference between pasting down as DateTime or double? Value2 essentially returns a double from both which is expected but if I paste down as a DateTime Excel also formats it as such. With the OLE Automation Date it formats as a double and then needs post formatting by me.

Comment: If you paste the string "2/1/2012" it could either end up as 2nd of jan or 1st of feb. Setting the double is guaranteed to be correct regardless of culture, cell formatting and/or regional settings.